# Aliasing/mapping a network device in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, device

In Ubuntu, I have two ethernet interfaces eth1 and eth3 that I want to call "foo0" and "foo1", respectively. Basically, I want something like "ip link alias DEVICE SECONDNAME". Is there a way to do this without mucking in the kernel?

Comment: Just to clarify, I would like something like "ip link alias eth1 foo0" in the example above.

Comment: Why? It doesn't make sense, does it? Edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to give them a different name. This is not an alias, it is a renaming.

Comment: Adding a duplicate line in 70-persistent-net.rules doesn't work: only the last rule for the device is used.

Comment: I didn't say that you are allowed to **add** a line. I said you should **edit** a line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu you can change the name of interfaces in **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules**. That would be far and away the simplest solution.

If there is a real need for the interface to be aliased as foo0 rather than be renamed then you can do something dirty with bridge-tools.

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

then edit your **/etc/network/interfaces** file to be something like..

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual


auto foo0 
iface foo0 inet static     
address 192.168.10.10     
netmask 255.255.255.0     
vlan-raw-device eth0     
bridge_ports vlan10
```

Comment: Here is a guide to rename the interface: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04#801310